# Gaussian blur without refreshing

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, gaussianblur

I want to know if there is a way to create a gaussian blur effect in kivy without the screen refreshing so much when the widget is animated or its size changes. Whenever I put anything in an EffectWidget and resize the app, it starts blinking like crazy. Isn't there an optimal way of doing this? Achieving a blur effect without refreshing so many times?

**EDIT:** this is the standard way of doing of achieving a blur effect using **Effectwidget**, however, I would like the screen to stop refreshing it is resized or animated:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
#:import ew kivy.uix.effectwidget
EffectWidget:
    effects: ew.HorizontalBlurEffect(size=8), ew.VerticalBlurEffect(size=8)
    FitImage:
        source: "images/song_img.jpg"
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson I added a minimal reproducible example. I want an image to have this same blur effect but won't refresh like the effectwidget